# Why won't Python recognize the module I imported, or the dictionary I create?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm just trying to create an ordered dictionary for the alphabet. I have the following code:

```
>>> import string
>>> od = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, range(1, 27)))
>>> od
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 97, in <module>
NameError: name 'string' is not defined
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Python 3.7
Clang 9.1

Comment: [mcve] please. The code you posted neither has 97 lines, nor is it coming from `<string>`.

Comment: The three lines you posted execute fine for me.  There's something going on above your code. Likely you're re-declaring 'string' somewhere.